# How to signal end of input to powershell at runtime?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell I have ran command `remove-item -recurse` Now it is asking for path as input ,I have provided 3 paths at path[0],path[1],and path[2], and again it is asking for input for path[3]. I think it will keep asking until I signal end of input to Powershell.

I have tried `ctrl+c` which escaped me from asking input but it prevent the execution of commands.

I need to know how can I signal end of the input to powershell so that it not only stops asking me for the input but executes the commands.

Note: I don't want to use for loop  as I am not providing path in advance. I want to provide path at runtime and also signal end of input at runtime itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered by mistake that If I press `enter` without providing any input then it will stop asking for input anymore and it will execute the command for other provided input.